# ChromeDriver gets the wrong button location, so clicks on it will fail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, telerik-radbutton

I am writing a robot web client with chromedriver.
In a certain webpage, I get different results depending on if I am running the test in a service or not. I am trying to click a button inside an iframe with code like this:

```
webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);

var element = webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("Button1"));
element.Click();
```

## If I run the test on an integration server (cruise control).

The buttons Location property is 930, -14 (and Size is 31, 21).

Clicks are failing with the following message:

> Element is not clickable at point (945, -4)

## If I run the test in a desktop application (winforms)

The position is correctly calculated as 16,621 (the width and height are reported as 85, 20).

The button can be clicked.

## Problem

How do I proceed with this? I seek a method to come closer to finding out what happens.

Comment: I have mixed up buttons, closing question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the error message

> Element is not clickable at point (x, y)

ends with text something like another element would receive the click and then it goes on to log the HTML of the element that would receive the click. Find that element in the DOM. Many times it's some dynamic HTML that isn't done loading, maybe a dialog that isn't fully dismissed, etc. Try waiting for the element to be invisible using `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions`.

Also make sure that there isn't a id = button1 on the previous page that might be getting picked up if the pages are transitioning or loading slowly. You might need to wait for the element to go stale (to ensure the page transition has started) before looking for it on the new page.

Comment: The exception message does not end as you describe. The button is there because else I would not be able to retrieve its location and size by using its properties. There is no other page before because the click is in the middle of a sequence, the previous one being a click on an `<option>`. I also try a lot of times waiting a second between each try, every time with that incorrect button location and size.

Comment: I have mixed up buttons, closing question.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem in chrome many times, and the workaround for me is to use javascript's scrollIntoView to move the visible viewport to that element.

There are two reasons why you would get an 'element not visible' error:

1. The element is not within the visible bounds of the browser window
   selenium has opened;
2. The element is hidden through CSS (it is under another element, or has it's visibility set to false)

Using scrollIntoView will **always** cover the first of those possible problems. No matter how wide or high your page view is, scrollIntoView locates the element by it's ID and moves the visible browser area to that element. Essentially it emulates using scrollbars until it can physically see that element on screen.

The second problem is of course a styling issue, but you could also manipulate that element with raw javascript (set CSS properties on it, etc)

Not tested, but this should work:

```
WebDriver.executeScript(
    'var elm = document.getElementById("Button1");elm.scrollIntoView(true);'
);
// Continue to access element: WebDriver.By.Id("Button1").Click();
// You could also click the element through javascript:
// Example:
// var elm = document.getElementById("Button1");elm.scrollIntoView(true);elm.click();
// if doing the above make sure you remove the WebDriver.click()l line.
```

Using this will also cover cases where you are testing chrome on different platforms with variable screen sizes. No matter what the screen size, using scrollIntoView before interacting with an element will always give consistent results. I find selenium testing flaky at best and chrome is sometimes so rapid it causes inconsistent results. Doing this before each interaction is probably the biggest single change I made to make selenium testing a bit more reliable.

Some more info on scrollIntoView: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: But the button is in a completely wrong position. Is it hard for chromedriver to get the position of the button if it is further down on the page?

Comment: I added a scrollIntoView line even if I was using `IJavaScriptExecutor`, but the click is failing in the same way, with the same reported button location.

Comment: the button being in the wrong position is a styling issue, no? from chromedriver/selenium's point of view, it doesn't matter what the position is: scrollIntoView will always navigate to wherever it is as it does it by the element ID. If the click fails after, try doing that in raw javascript also: I'll change the answer above to do it that way also.

Comment: Also: do you take screenshots when your tests fail?

Comment: Yes, the button is there in the screenshot at the expected position. Your javascript code does not enter the iframe.

Comment: I have mixed up buttons, closing question.

Comment: You already enter the iframe with your code from the question, so I omitted that part.

Comment: So ExecuteScript runs in the entered frame?

Comment: if you switch to the correct iframe first, then yes. Just place the switchTo above the executeScript line.

Comment: I found out that my problem was 1. mixing buttons, 2. having insufficient height of window, so the iframe got a negative position (caused by script that wants to center it in height).